# Break one jQuery Easing plugin animation into two (left + right)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing

I have this code in which [jQuery Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) is being used to switch between Testimonials.

This code can be seen here (go to Testimonials section): http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/3hkwz/

When you open the Testimonials section, you'll see 2 buttons at the bottom for switch left (called `prev`) and right (called `next`) between the Testimonials.

The code works, but it uses the same `scrollLeft`Easing animation for going both left and right. I want to update the code so that when `prev` is clicked, the animation used should be `scrollRight`, not `scrollLeft` ..

The same JavaScript is used to link both `prev` and `next`'s clicks to the same Easing animation code:

```
$('.scrollable4 .items').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',
    speed:700,
    timeout: 0,
    next: '.next',
    prev: '.prev',
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
})
```

How do I split them up ?

Also, there is an attached JavaScript resource file which contains some relevant code:

Deminify this: http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/js/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js

Then go to line 118, and you'll see this snippet:

```
case "prev":
case "next":
    var u = i(q).data("cycle.opts");
    if (!u) {
        f('options not found, "prev/next" ignored');
        return false
    }
    i.fn.cycle[t](u);
    return false;
```

So can someone help me here ? I'm baffled ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your fx transition to `scrollHorz` it handles automatically the correct direction.

Code:

```
$('.scrollable4 .items').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed:700,
    timeout: 0,
    next: '.next',
    prev: '.prev',
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/TE9Bq/

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think it was going to be that easy !

Comment: @Ahmad Glad to help you; fortunately the easing library is pretty full of effects!